# C preprocessor macro to convert string of Fortran program to lowercase?

Tags: c++, fortran, lowercase

I would like to do the following:

In a FORTRAN program

call myPackageFunction("MPI_User_function")

...shall be transfered BY A C PREPROCESSOR MAKRO to...

call myPackageFunction("mpi_user_function_")

The reason why I want to do that is that the user of my package (an average MATLAB and Fortran user) doesn't have to know about the name mangling of Fortran, but in the same time doing this task for the user shall not slow done the package function.

Does someone know how I could do that? I would be most grateful for any help!

Comment: When is the transform going to happen, is the users' FORTRAN code going to be run through the C preprocessor? This isn'tv very clear.

Comment: Yes, the users' FORTRAN code going to be run through the C preprocessor. The user has to include "myPackage.h" in order to call myPackageFunction. So I could define a makro in there. Maybe something like: #define myPackageFunction(string) myPackageFunction(<lowercaseString>)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass C routines to a Fortran subroutine, is this right?   Using Fortran2003 Fortran<->C interoperability, you can avoid the whole name mangling issue, but it would be easier if we knew more about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I know about interoperabilty features. However for my package the difference between the c and fortran name mangling is to my favour except for this little issue.
=> I will follow Oli Charlesworth's answer and create a little pre-preprocessor-script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C preprocessor cannot do this sort of transformation.

You will probably need to write a custom script that does this, that is automatically called by your build system before the compiler runs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Why can't  the C preprocessor cannot do this sort of transformation? because there's no way at all to access the individual chars of the string?

Comment: @Sam: The preprocessor is *extremely* limited in what it can do.  Basically, it can only do simple copy-and-paste-like functionality.

Comment: Thank you everyone who read my post => I will follow Oli Charlesworth's answer and create a little pre-preprocessor-script.